# world map in terms of latitude and longitude

Tags: java

Provided with two locations on the world map in terms of latitude and longitude, print the distance between them. Note that the distance between two points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) is the square root of (x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2. Round up the value up to five decimal places.

Input Specification :

Input will be two points with each point containing First latitude and then longitude

Sample Input :

12.12345 80.44554

12.44554 80.12345

Sample Output :

0.45550

Comment: Try talking to [Jogesh Joby](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6386498/jogesh-joby), he asked an [identically-worded (but now deleted)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37462988/print-the-distance-note-that-the-distance-between-two-points-x1-y1-and-x2-y2) question yesterday.

Comment: Must be a homework assignement

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an unashamed homework dump.

Comment: "Note that the distance between two points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) is the square root of (x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2" That's not even close to being true, if those are latitudes and longitudes. Or, at least, it's not a meaningful number.

Comment: If you have a new question, please [ask it as a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Giant edits which completely change your question also invalidate any answers you have received, and as such are frowned upon.

Comment: @GauravMahindra "simple mathematical question" doesn't imply correctness. The original question was a homework dump and the edit, which I specifically referred to, was an entirely new question which would actually have invalidated your answer. Site policy is to ask new questions as new questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are :-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Distance {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
            double x1=0;
            double x2=0;
            double y1=0;
            double y2=0;
            double distance=0;

            System.out.println("Enter the value of x1 : ");
            x1=in.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter the value of y1 : ");
            y1=in.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter the value of x2 : ");
            x2=in.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter the value of y2 : ");
            y2=in.nextDouble();

            distance=Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x2-x1), 2)+Math.pow((y2-y1), 2));
            System.out.printf("The distance between given coordinates is : %.5f",distance);
        }
    }
```